# Clickonce WPF application publish no option to specify deployment url

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I'm having a problem with one of my projects where I am not able to specify my deployment url for Clickonce in the .application file, here is the expected piece of Xml

```
 <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" co.v1:createDesktopShortcut="true">
    <deploymentProvider codebase="http://www.mycompany.co.uk/ClickOnce/myapplication/myapplication.application" />
  </deployment>
```

Here is my other project where I have only the following

```
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" co.v1:createDesktopShortcut="true" />
```

In my second project I want to be able to specify my url in the .application file but I have tried many of the available options and have not been able to find out what exactly I need to do to get it working. I am using Visual Studio 2013

Options under the properties-publish-options tabs are identical for Description, Deployment, Manifests

One noted difference is that my application type is WPF application for my working project, and my other project is of type Windows Application, and they look slightly different on the application tab, that seems to be the biggest difference between them, screenshot showing details below.

[image]

Comment: *I have tried many of the available options*... that's a very poor description. How are we meant to know what you have and have not tried? Please don't be lazy when asking questions, because then the answer authors would have to go through all of the possible options instead and it's not our job... it's *yours*.

Comment: Editing with list of things I have tried...will update sorry

Comment: Ok added what I have compared between the two projects now.

Comment: On your Publish tab, do you have the Publishing Folder Location field? That is where you're supposed to enter your published folder path.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "not working" a bit better? Do you get an error message? Does it not change the launch url?

Comment: Rachel. By working I mean the first snippet of xaml is generated in the .application file for my first project, which has a <deploymentProvider> with codebase url which is what I want. whereas in my second project it has only that single line <Deployment> and I need to be able to specify a url in deployment provider for that second project (so it appears basically identical to the first)

Comment: Sheridan, the Publishing Folder Locations for both of the projects are two folders on my local C:\ Drive

Comment: on the Publish tab, what is the installation folder URL? It has to be picking up http://www.mycompany.co.uk/ClickOnce/myapplication/myapplication.application from somewhere.

Comment: my installation folder URL for my project that includes the deployment provider is http://www.mycompany.co.uk/ClickOnce/myapplication/ my installation folder URL for my second project that does not have the deployment provider URL in the .application file is http://www.mycompany.co.uk/ClickOnce/myOtherApplication/

Comment: try using msbuild at a command prompt: msbuild.exe applicationProjectName.vbproj /t:publish /p:InstallURL=http://mycompany.co.uk/ClickOnce/Myapplication/myapplication.application

Comment: Can you tell us more about the the windows application. It can not be a WPF application so what is it?

Comment: It's located on **Publish** tab!

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your project , there is a tab called "Publish":

[image]